# How to install SciPy on OS X 10.11 in virtualenv with Python3

Tags: python, macos, scipy, python-3.5

I've got a bunch of Python 2.7 virtualenvs with the SciPy stack, and other libraries, all installed with pip. My system Python is whatever Apple ships in El Capitan.

I'd like to create a Python 3.5 virtualenv with the SciPy stack. To this end I have:

- installed python-3.5.1-macosx10.6.pkg from https://www.python.org/downloads/release/python-351/
- Installed Xcode 7.2.1 and downloaded and installed Command_Line_Tools_OS_X_10.11_for_Xcode_7.2.dmg from Apple.
- Installed fortran-5.2-Yosemite.dmg from http://gcc.gnu.org/wiki/GFortranBinaries

I created a virtualenv with "virtualenv.py -p `which python3` p3". I activated that virtualenv successfully, and ran "pip install jupyter", which succeed (giving me a working jupyter notebook running Python 3.5).

I then went "pip install scipy", but this failed with "could not find <endian.h>". I set the environment variable to help the C compiler find it in /usr/include/machine with: export CFLAGS="$CFLAGS -I/usr/include/machine", but then encountered "/usr/include/_types/_wctype_t.h:31:9: error: unknown type name '__darwin_wctype_t'"

This is starting to feel like a losing battle:

**Does someone have a recipe for installing SciPy with pip I could follow instead?**

The only additional caveat is that I don't wish to use brew or ports on my Mac - I just want to use pip and the command-line toolchain on my machine. I am OK with installing additional OS X packages like I did with Python 3.5 and gfortran above.

Comment: if you don't want to install homebrew you should consider saveosx.org it supplies prebuilt binaries (like in many linux distros) based on pkgsrc